# Listing all the months within a quarter using the Year and Quarter column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have put together a code which checks whether the string begins with Q1, Q2, Q3 or Q4, and if found it should display the start of that quarter.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
  name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO #Test
    (name) 
VALUES 
    ('Q324'),
    ('Q224')

SELECT 
    name 
    ,[Year] = '20' + RIGHT(name,2)
    ,[Quarter] = CASE 
                    WHEN LEFT(name,2) = 'Q1' THEN '01'
                    WHEN LEFT(name,2) = 'Q2' THEN '04'
                    WHEN LEFT(name,2) = 'Q3' THEN '07'
                    WHEN LEFT(name,2) = 'Q4' THEN '10'
                    ELSE NULL
                END
from #Test
```

**Output table:**

[image]

How do I now go about displaying all the months within those quarters?

**Expected Output:**

```
Name  Year   Quarter  MonthYear
Q324  2024     03      Jul-24
Q324  2024     03      Aug-24
Q324  2024     03      Sep-24
```

Comment: Consumable sample data will help us help you.

Comment: I've included a sample table I created

Comment: I must admit, I'm a little confused by your value for `Quarter`. What "quarter" is `7` and `10`? Quarters are are when something is split into 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method would be to use a `VALUES` table construct to add 0-2 months to the date, and then format it into the value you want:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT name 
          ,[Year] = '20' + RIGHT(name,2)
          ,[Quarter] = CASE 
                          WHEN LEFT(name,2) = 'Q1' THEN '01'
                          WHEN LEFT(name,2) = 'Q2' THEN '04'
                          WHEN LEFT(name,2) = 'Q3' THEN '07'
                          WHEN LEFT(name,2) = 'Q4' THEN '10'
                          ELSE NULL
                      END
    from #Test)
SELECT C.[Name],
       C.[Year],
       C.[Quarter],
       CONCAT(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEFROMPARTS(C.[Year], C.[Quarter] + V.I,1)),3),'-',Year) AS MonthYear
FROM CTE C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(0),(1),(2))V(I)
ORDER BY C.Year,
         C.Quarter,
         V.I;
```

Note that this could very likely be made more succinct, but I incorporated your existing code, rather than completely rewriting it.

Comment: Great minds think nearly alike

Comment: Yeah, I intentionally avoided `FORMAT`, @Charlieface , as I've been stung by it's (gross) performance in the past.

Comment: All kinds of ugly ways to do it, e.g. `SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6), 6), ' ', '-');`

Answer (score 2):

You can join it with an inline virtual table of numbers to add

```sql
SELECT 
  name,
  v1.Year,
  [Quarter] = FORMAT(v1.Month, '00'),
  MonthYear = FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(v1.Year, v1.Month + v2.MonthsToAdd, 1), 'MMM-yy')
from #Test t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    '20' + RIGHT(name,2),
    CASE LEFT(name,2)
        WHEN 'Q1' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Q2' THEN 4
        WHEN 'Q3' THEN 7
        WHEN 'Q4' THEN 10
    END
)) v1(Year, Month)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (0),(1),(2)
) v2(MonthsToAdd);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e742a44b0e23013cefd3274777c30600)

Note the use of `CROSS APPLY` to be able to access the calculated values

Comment: I agree with Larnu and would really stay away from `FORMAT()`, though. `CONVERT()` and other approaches are [abouit twice as fast in my testing](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).

Comment: It is much more flexible and simple though. I suppose it depends on how many rows you're talking, YMMV

Comment: Kind of like `.[1]` vs. `/text()` eh? :-) I’m certainly going to nitpick about things I blog about and include in every Bad Habits presentation I give because we just don’t know what scale this OP or any other future reader will apply this “flexible” approach to.

Comment: Hah, well played, checkmate..... We're just trying to get the best solution here, I don't care about nitpicking, here's a licecomb.... :-) I went for `FORMAT` rather than `DATENAME` from the start mainly because OP wants the short form of the month eg `Jul` and that's much better to do in .NET because it knows how different cultures work with short month names